# How to load a prepared server to GAE?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a net game with swing applet clients and server for managing. (Server based on Sockets)
I always ran it locally and I want to upload it to GAE.
I would like to know how do I upload the server and client applet ,step by step in eclipse to GAE and also would like to know which port I will need in my game in which run locally on port 7777.

Thanks

Comment: You can't. GAE limits you to a Servlet interface; you can't control sockets yourself and can only respond to HTTP requests.

Comment: @Wooble beat me to the punch. This is one of those instances where if you're looking for a cloud solution, an AWS EC2 instance is the btter route (can bind to any socket).

Comment: okay so what are my options if I want to try it in sockets method
Do you know any good free services for that?

Answer (score 0):

Google App Engine provides a Platform as a Service. If you want your app to run on App Engine, you have to write it for App Engine, and with the restrictions it has in mind - for instance, you can't open arbitrary sockets.